# How to Insert dollar Sign before number value

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner with MySQL.

How do I insert a dollar sign before my values turning `23457.50` into `$23,457.50`.

```
insert into rep VALUES (
    15, 
    'Campos',
    'Rafael', 
    '724 Vinca Dr.',
    'Grove',
    'CA', 
    90092, 
    23457.50, 
    0.06
);
```

Comment: You can't if the column is a float / double type. My recommendation though, is don't bother as you can format it how you like when you want to render it, which also lets you keep the benefits of keeping the DB type as a number.

Comment: Handle this kind of thing in your application code

Comment: Or store the currency in a different column

Comment: You can do this with the help of front-end. Don't store it in back-end. Whenever required you can access by formatting the same.

Answer (score 0):

You must not store the values as `$` prepend in the database. By doing this numbers will get converted to varchar and might be problematic in later calculation. You should use format function while selecting them instead -

```
SELECT CONCAT('$', FORMAT(23457.50,2)) RESULT

RESULT
$23,457.50
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f3e9663848a0dbab8f4d2bfbdf9e2fa0) is the fiddle.